# How to extract appservice plan from appservice list command output

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to extract appservice plan name with `--query` and it's not working.

I have created an appservice plan with

```sh
az appservice plan create --name "mydev-app-plan" --resource-group "myrg"
```

and with

```
az appservice plan list
```

I can list it successfully. Now I want to extract the name of the plan that I have created using

```
az appservice plan list --query "name"
```

But it's not extracting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use the following syntax:

```
az appservice plan list --query '[].name'
```

This should give you an output like following:

```
[
  "PlanA",
  "PlanB",
  ...
]
```